# Same name for a static variable within a static member function

Tags: c++, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are static variables with the same name in different functions identified by the System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756940/how-are-static-variables-with-the-same-name-in-different-functions-identified-by)

How does compiler make the difference between two local static variables that have the same name, but are defined in two different (static) member functions?

```
class Type
{
    public:
        static void fun()
        {
            static bool sameName = false;

            // work with sameName

        }
        static void moreFun()
        {
            static bool sameName = false;

            // work with sameName
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it has to do with scope.

the sameName exists in two different scopes / in this case two function scopes

so internally the variables maybe are referred to with names fun.sameName and moreFun.sameName (names just arbtitrary invented by me but show the principle).

Comment: This is what I thought. There is no way to access those variables from outside of functions, even if they are existing for the duration of the program?

Comment: @tomislav-maric If the function returns a pointer or reference to them, then you can access them outside the function using that pointer/reference.  Otherwise, there's no way to get at them (well, it may be possible if you're running it in a debugger to inspect them -- that would depend on the debugger).

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ SPEC(eg:N3337) say:

> 3 The keyword static can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duraion.
>
> (Page: 62; section 3.7.1 Static storage duration)

In your case, the variable `static bool sameName` is belong to the scope of the function `fun`. And the other variable `static bool sameName` is belong to the scope of the function `moreFun`. These two static variables belong to different scope. The `static` keyword effect to duration only, it's not effect scope.