# Is a static variable name, same as function name allowed in C?

Tags: c, static, name-mangling

I was working on some C-output questions and found the following code:

http://ideone.com/O0tQnr

In this code , as one can see , inside main , a static variable having same name has been declared.  For this I searched on Stack-Overflow and found

[How are static variables with the same name in different functions identified by the System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756940/how-are-static-variables-with-the-same-name-in-different-functions-identified-by)

The answers given for this question suggest different approaches viz.

1. The names of static variables are usually included within the debugging symbol table.
2. some embedded ones (compilers) simply add a number to the end of each duplicate name
3. They are likely mangled in the table.

I wanted to know how are static variables actually implemented in C, as all answers are suggesting something different?

Also to check whether this was only a one-off chance I also ran the code:

http://ideone.com/zpRVCa

but the error:

```
prog.c:5:21: error: called object ‘GetSize’ is not a function or function pointer
int myvar=GetSize(GetSize);
                 ^
prog.c:4:11: note: declared here
static GetSize;
       ^
```

indicates that the compiler found a conflicting declaration / redeclared Getsize.

Comment: "how are static variables actually implemented in C" -- that depends on the implementation, which is why there are different answers.

Comment: Ok , I agree different implementations on different platforms, but then why is there an error in the second code, the compiler should have resolved the doubt , as variable names are being stored differently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different entities may have the same identifier if they have different scopes or are in different name spaces<sup>1</sup>. In the case of `int main() { static int main; … }`, the first `main` has file scope, and the second `main` has block scope.

At any particular point, only one identifier is visible in a name space. In `GetSize(GetSize)`, only the `static GetSize` is visible. It hides the `int GetSize(int)`, so the function `GetSize` is not visible. Thus, this code gets an error.

An identifier declared at file scope with `static` has internal linkage. An object identifier declared at block scope without `extern` (including those that have `static`) has no linkage. Because these identifiers do not have external linkage, they never need to be known outside the current translation unit. Therefore, these identifiers do not need to appear in object files: There is no need for them to have names visible to the linker. They are typically accessed by code generated by the compiler during compilation of the translation unit, and this code addresses objects numerically (by location in memory), not by name.

Many C implementations provide debugging facilities. Debuggers generally need to know the names of things even if they have internal or no linkage. In these cases, the C implementation may use any scheme it desires to record information about names.

---

<sup>1</sup> The name spaces of C are: label names; tags of structures, unions and enumerations; members of structures or unions (a separate space for each structure or union); and all other identifiers. The standard also refers to a name space for macro names.

Comment: so, I assume that the line "Many C implementations provide debugging facilities. Debuggers generally need to know the names of things even if they have internal or no linkage. In these cases, the C implementation may use any scheme it desires to record information about names." means to say that static variables can be treated just like other variables and can be stored anywhere. Am I right?

Comment: @DrefD: Generally, static objects can be stored anywhere in the program’s general data (separate from the stack or the space used for dynamic memory allocations or other special areas). Each implementation has its own scheme for handling data. While compiling a program, a compiler will end up with a bunch of objects that exist for the entire lifetime of the program: Objects declared with `extern`, objects declared with `static`, some constants, whatever. It could throw these into one big area and use them however it pleases. All it needs to do is tell the linker where the `extern` ones are.

Comment: @DrefD: So the symbol table in the object module has to say “This external `foo` is at offset 80 in the data, this external `bar` is at 1020” and so on. But the symbol table does not have to say anything about the objects with internal or no linkage. They are private, not visible externally. But they are there, just with numbers and no names. Except a debugging section might have information that does list the names and their offsets in the data. In this case, the implementation has to have a scheme for keeping the names straight. That scheme is not dictated by the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

The two cases you are describing have a fundamental difference. In the first case:

```
int main(){
   static main;
   int myvar=GetSize(main);
   printf("%d",myvar);
   return 0;
}
```

Here, you are inside the function `main` and declaring a static integer also called `main`. The function `main` is called from an external place which knows about `main` as a function and calls it as such. Inside the definition of `main` above, you have redefined `main` as the static integer, then calling `GetSize(main)` doesn't cause an error because it complies with the definition of `GetSize`.

In the second case:

```
int GetSize(int);
int main(){
   static GetSize;
   int myvar=GetSize(GetSize);
   printf("%d",myvar);
   return 0;
}
```

Here you've redefined `GetSize` to be a static integer, but then attempted to call `GetSize` as if it were a function. So you have a direct conflict in terms of the definition (static integer) and how you are using it (a function).

Comment: agreed, http://ideone.com/WLgAOc , here conflict does take place as you point out, but my point is , if static variables are already being stored in the debugging symbol table , then why does a conflict occour in the first place? The third answer to that questions even mentions    function overloading.

Comment: @DrefD: Not all answers submitted by people to Stack Overflow are correct or relevant. Also, there is no “third answer”; answers with equal votes are presented in a randomized order. To refer to a specific answer, you should provide a link to it.

Comment: I was referring to the answer by Alex Budovski.

Answer (score 0):

There's a clue in the error message: "not a function *or function pointer*". The compiler can't assume that the name to the left of the `(` is a function name, because any expression yielding a function pointer is also allowed there, including a variable declared as a function pointer.

At the parsing stage, there's no type checking to help find the right variable. Here's a program that doesn't work for a similar reason:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct { int x,y; } s = {0,0};
  {
    int s;
    printf("%d\n", s.x);
  }
}
```

The outer `s` is capable of fitting into the expression `s.x`, but the inner `s` is the one that is visible.

And here's a program that works *because* the outer-scoped function is not preferred over the inner-scoped variable, which happens to be a function pointer capable of being called with itself as an argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func()
{
  puts("Everything's fine.");
}

void fp()
{
  /* This won't happen. */
  abort();
}

int main(void)
{
  void (*fp)() = func;
  fp(fp);
}
```