# memory allocated to static variables in C

Tags: c, static

```
int a, b, c = 0;

void prtFun(void);

int main()
{
    static int a = 1; /* line 1 */
    prtFun();
    a += 1;
    prtFun();
    printf("\n %d %d ", a, b);
}

void prtFun(void)
{
    static int a = 2; /* line 2 */
    int b = 1;
    a += ++b;
    printf(" \n %d %d ", a, b);
}
```

The output to the above program is:

4,2

6,2

2,0

The local variables are generally stored in the stack of the function and the global variables and the static variables are stored in the data segment of the process right? in that case does having the same static variable name in multiple functions cause any conflicts? how are variables referred to in the data segment?

Comment: It's up to the compiler where data is stored, or whether it is stored at all.

Comment: @venkat The question is unclear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i have edited my question. hope its clearer now

Comment: See also [How are static variables with the same name in different functions identified by the System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756940/how-are-static-variables-with-the-same-name-in-different-functions-identified-by)

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you ask the question **format your code correctly**

```
int a, b, c = 0; 

void prtFun (void); 
int main(void) 
{ 
    static int a = 1; /* line 1 */
    prtFun(); 
    a += 1; 
    prtFun(); 
    printf ( "\n %d %d " , a, b) ; 
} 

void prtFun (void) 
{ 
    static int a = 2; /* line 2 */
    int b = 1; 
    a += ++b; 
    printf (" \n %d %d " , a, b); 
}
```

`prtFun`

`b` is an automatic variable and it is initialized every time you call this function.
`a` is static local variable and it is initialised only once and it keeps its value between the function calls. But its scope is local to the function `prtFun`

So when you call it first time `a` is assigned 4 and `b` is assigned 2. You print this values

in function `main` another `a` static local variable is assigned value of 2 (initialization + increment).

when you call the `prtFun` again you add 2 to the function own `a` variable which keeps the value from the previous call (4) and the result is 6. The `b` is initialized again to 1 and pre-incremented - so it 2.

Then in function main you print its own `a` variable (which is 2) and global variable `b`  which is 0